# How to realize contraction between two sparse tensor?

Tags: algorithm, sparse-matrix, tensor

I want to know how to realize contraction between two sparse tensors? efficiently.

I know how the algorithm for product between two sparse matrix.
I find pytorch have sparse tensor, but I didn't find contraction operator.

Comment: According to the pytorch sparse docs, `matmul` is the only operator defined for the csr format, https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html